# Show this inequality $\dfrac{\sin{\frac{B}{2}}}{\sin{A}+\sin{B}}+\dfrac{\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}{\sin{A}+\sin{C}}\le\dfrac{1}{2\sin{A}}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

For any $\triangle ABC$, prove or disprove $$\dfrac{\sin{\frac{B}{2}}}{\sin{A}+\sin{B}}+\dfrac{\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}{\sin{A}+\sin{C}}\le\dfrac{1}{2\sin{A}}$$
by $$\sin{A}+\sin{B}=2\sin{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{A-B}{2}}$$
$$\sin{A}+\sin{C}=2\sin{\dfrac{A+C}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{A-C}{2}}$$

This leads to prove
$$\dfrac{\sin{\frac{B}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{A+B}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{A-B}{2}}}+\dfrac{\sin{\frac{C}{2}}}{\sin{\dfrac{A+C}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{A-C}{2}}}\le\dfrac{1}{\sin{A}}$$

Comment: Should the $\sum$ on the LHS of the question have 3 terms, or only two terms as you indicate?

Comment: Note that $A+B=\pi-C$

Comment: @Blitzer,two terms,

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle. We may suppose that $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$, and $c=x+z.$ If $p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$, one can show that:

$$\sin \frac{B}{2}=\sqrt {\frac{(p-a)(p-c)}{ac}} =\sqrt{\frac{yz}{(x+y)(x+z)}}\\\sin \frac{C}{2}=\sqrt {\frac{(p-a)(p-b)}{ab}}=\sqrt{\frac{zx}{(x+y)(y+z)}}.$$

Moreover, $\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c}$; hence, we just need to verify the relations below:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{yz}{(x+y)(x+z)}}}{(x+y)+(y+z)}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{zx}{(x+y)(y+z)}}}{(x+y)+(x+z)} \leq \frac{1}{2(x+y)} \\ \iff \frac{\sqrt {yz(x+y)}}{((x+y)+(y+z))\sqrt{x+z}}+\frac{\sqrt {zx(x+y)}}{((x+y)+(x+z))\sqrt {y+z}} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

On the other hand, we have:

$$\frac{\sqrt {yz(x+y)}}{((x+y)+(y+z))\sqrt{x+z}}+\frac{\sqrt {zx(x+y)}}{((x+y)+(x+z))\sqrt {y+z}} \\ \leq \frac{\sqrt {yz(x+y)}}{2\sqrt{(x+y)(y+z)}\sqrt {x+z}}+\frac{\sqrt {zx(x+y)}}{2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\sqrt{y+z}}=\frac{\sqrt {yz}+\sqrt{xz}}{2\sqrt{y+z}\sqrt{x+z}};$$

but:
$$\frac{\sqrt {yz}+\sqrt{xz}}{2\sqrt{y+z}\sqrt{x+z}} \leq \frac {1}{2};$$

because:

$$\sqrt {yz}+\sqrt{xz} \leq \sqrt{y+z}\sqrt{x+z} \\ \iff z(\sqrt x +\sqrt y)^2 \leq (y+z)(z+x)=z^2+zx+zy+xy \\ \iff 2z\sqrt {xy} \leq z^2+xy,$$

which is clear.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the standard notation  by AM-GM and C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin\frac{\beta}{2}}{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}+\frac{\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma}=2R\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}}{2}}}{a+b}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}}{2}}}{a+c}\right)=$$
$$=R\left(\frac{\sqrt{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)}}{\sqrt{ac}(a+b)}+\frac{\sqrt{(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}}{\sqrt{ab}(a+c)}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq R\left(\frac{\sqrt{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)}}{\sqrt{ac}\cdot2\sqrt{ab}}+\frac{\sqrt{(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}}{\sqrt{ab}\cdot2\sqrt{ac}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(a+b-c)(b+c-a)}+\sqrt{(a+c-b)(b+c-a)}}{4\sqrt{bc}\sin\alpha}\leq$$
$$\leq \frac{\sqrt{(b+c-a+a+c-b)(a+b-c+b+c-a)}}{4\sqrt{bc}\sin\alpha}=\frac{1}{2\sin\alpha}.$$